# Ember.js itemController controller leaking variable

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an itemController that has two fields: `isExpanded` and `newComment`. The `isExpanded` is working great and binding to each itemController, but the newComment is somehow shared by all the instances of the itemController. And it will only share for the first time. After I submit the new comment, that textarea no longer share the same binding with other textareas, but the rest of the textareas are still mysteriously binding to the same ghost `newComment`. Why?

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gojuhega/1/edit

[1]Previous question removed and isolated to this jsbin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems when new controllers are created based on `DiscussionController` prototype, its properties are shallow-copied. Since your `newComment` is a reference type, you end up with 3 controllers all sharing a same instance. Only when you click 'Create' do individual controllers get their own instances.

One potential solution:

```
App.DiscussionController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  isExpanded: false,

  newComment: null,
  actions: {
    toggleExpand: function(){
      this.toggleProperty('isExpanded');
      if (!this.get("newComment")) {
        this.set("newComment", {body:""});
      }
    },
    createComment: function() {
      this.set('newComment', {
        body: ''
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: An alternative solution would be to use `init` to setup default values per instance (don't forget to call `this._super()` though).

Comment: Thanks all! Christoffer also cited this issue on ember.discuss for a full explanation: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/462